How to connect as a coach in conference when agent receives a call in Twilio php
In this scenario when an agent create an outbound call then another user wants to join that conference as a coach it's working
When an agent receives a call and other user wants to join that conference as coach then it starts coaching to client not to the agent the leg is not working for this scenario:
This is because when I get the participants callsids in which the agent and client is connected so in that leg the from number is client's number and coach attribute gets the from number from that callsid and start coaching to that I need guidance in this:
    public function makecoach(){
  $conferenceSid = $this->input->post('conferencesid');
    $agentCallSid = $this->input->post('callsid');
    $participantsid = $this->input->post('participantcallsid');
    $client = new Client($this->config->item('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'), $this->config->item('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_TOKEN'));
    // Fetch the list of participants in the conference
    $participants = $client->conferences($conferenceSid)
        ->participants
        ->read();

    // Find the participant's CallSid
    $participantCallSid = null;
    foreach ($participants as $p) {
        if ($p->callSid === $participantsid) {
            $participantCallSid = $p->callSid;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($participantCallSid) {
        // Set the participant as a coach
        $client->conferences($conferenceSid)
            ->participants($participantCallSid)
            ->update([
                'coaching' => true,
                'callSidToCoach' => $agentCallSid // The CallSid of the participant you want to coach
            ]);

        echo json_encode(['status' => 'Supervisor added to conference in coach mode.']);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'Error', 'message' => $participantCallSid]);
    }
}


